# Generating Apache POI xlsx file with Spring Boot Java in Docker

Tags: java, docker, apache-poi

I have app that generates PDF with iTextPdf and now I have added Apache POI to generate Excel file on the same data. Front is JS with jQuery and backend is Java 11 (openJDK) with Spring Boot, Apache POI 5.0.
The problem is that everything works fine while running in IDE. File is generated and downloads with no problems. The problem occurs when I run apps docker container. If I try to generate Excel file I get error: `java.io.IOException: org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`with no "Caused by".
I use ByteArrayOutputStream and OutputStream to generate xlsx file and download it in browser. I don't try to store file in some folder and I don't use Docker volumes. Maybe Apache POI uses some temp folder while generating file? And it can't do this while runs from Docker?

Thanks in advance.

Controller:

```
try {
    Workbook workbook = excelGenerators.getExcelWorkbook(filteredList);

    ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        workbook.write(boas);
    } finally {
        boas.close();
    }

    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=report.xlsx");
    response.setContentLength(boas.size());
    
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    boas.writeTo(os);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
}
```

ExcelGenerator:

```
public Workbook getExcelWorkbook(List<FullOrder> orderList) {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("SHEET ONE");
        sheet.createFreezePane(0, 1);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 16000);
        ...

        CellStyle headerStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
        headerStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.AQUA.index);
        headerStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        headerStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

        XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontName("Arial");
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);
        font.setBold(true);
        headerStyle.setFont(font);

        Row header = sheet.createRow(0);

        Cell headerCell = header.createCell(0);
        headerCell.setCellValue("Klientas");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        ... 

        CellStyle singleOrderCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        singleOrderCellStyle.setWrapText(true);
        singleOrderCellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);

        AtomicInteger rowCount = new AtomicInteger(1);

        orderList.forEach(order -> {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount.get());

            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(order.getClient().getLabel());
            cell.setCellStyle(singleOrderCellStyle);

            ...

            rowCount.getAndIncrement();
        });

        CellStyle totalStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
        totalStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_ORANGE.index);
        totalStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        totalStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

        XSSFFont fontTotal = workbook.createFont();
        fontTotal.setFontName("Arial");
        fontTotal.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);
        fontTotal.setBold(true);
        totalStyle.setFont(fontTotal);

        Row totalRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount.get());

        Cell cell = totalRow.createCell(0);
        cell = totalRow.createCell(1);
        cell = totalRow.createCell(2);


        cell = totalRow.createCell(3);
        cell.setCellValue(totalCount[0]);
        cell.setCellStyle(totalStyle);

        cell = totalRow.createCell(4);
        cell = totalRow.createCell(5);

        cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(decimalFormat.format(totalSum[0]).replace(',', '.')));
        cell.setCellStyle(totalStyle);

        return workbook;
    }
```

I have changed catch with `logger.error(e.getClass() + ": " +  e.getMessage() + ": " + e.getCause(), e);` and now stack trace looks like this:

```
2021-05-17 12:09:34.060 ERROR 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.s.l.controller.ManagementController    : class org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.newDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:111) ~[poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.createRelationship(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:588) ~[poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    ... 95 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56) ~[poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.newDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:109) ~[poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    ... 96 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFont.addNewFamily()Lorg/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTIntProperty;
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont.setFamily(XSSFFont.java:602) ~[poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont.setFamily(XSSFFont.java:614) ~[poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.createDefaultFont(StylesTable.java:765) ~[poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.initialize(StylesTable.java:716) ~[poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.<init>(StylesTable.java:130) ~[poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    ... 102 common frames omitted
```

After adding or changing jars related to apache poi to version 3.17 I get another error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable
```

Comment: How are you spinning up a docker container?

Comment: I use this command: docker run --name my-app -p 8080:8080 --link my-app-mariadb:mysql -d docker_user/my-app:version_number   I run it on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: application/vnd.ms-excel is not the correct mime type for xlsx - it is for the legacy xls format - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet is correct

Comment: could you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: Full stacktrace added to question. Thanks for format type.

Comment: can you use `throw new IOException(e.getMessage(), e)`? -- adding the cause exception means you will get the stacktraces of the cause exception

Comment: Why aren't you writing directly to the outputstream which would save memory. Also the error tells you what is wrong `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFont.addNewFamily()Lorg/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTIntProperty;` looks like you are mixing jars from different versions op Apache POI. Finally don't call `close` on the outputstream it will be closed by the servlet container. You closing it will lead to other issues.

Comment: I have updated my exception with logger.error

Comment: I have checked other answers on 'Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFont.addNewFamily()Lorg/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTIntProperty;' and many answers says that I have to add poi-ooxml-schemas. It's strange to me, that if I run app from IDE, thn it's working just fine. If I run from Docker (I didn't tried to run jar), then it doesn't works. Apapche POI versions are the same - 5.0

Comment: Problem solved. The solution was to reduce apache poi versions to 3.17 version and reduce xmlbeans version to 2.6.0.  Next step is to try make work with apache poi latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to reduce apache poi versions to 3.17 version and reduce xmlbeans version to 2.6.0

Comment: I don't think downgrading and introducing vulnerabilities into your code is a good solution

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as you, the Apache POI version I'm using is 5.2.3. Then I found a solution by adding a command like this to the Dockerfile

```
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache fontconfig ttf-dejavu
```